# Hyperlink Autogenerated Image in PHP

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm building a site for one of my very first clients using [Wordpress' Simplicity-Lite Theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/simplicity-lite).

I'd like to alter the theme somehow so as to hyperlink my images in the featured-boxes position (Right below the slideshowshow) to open up a page in the same window.

The problem is that the images are automatically generated/fetched by a PHP script that picks them up from the media gallery and so one script does it all for all the eight images.

I want to make each of these images as fetched by PHP link to its own page to add interactivity to my site but I've tried several things but all in vain both in the **style.css** and the **featured-box.php** files.

I think it's because  I can't find element to hyperlink since it's auto-generated.

Below is a section of the PHP script in the **featured-box.php** file that fetches the 8 images and places them in the featured-boxes positions:

```
<div id="featured-boxs">
<?php foreach (range(1,8) as $fboxn) { ?>
<span class="featured-box"> 
<img class="box-image" src="<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn,   get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn . '.png') ?>"/>
<h3><?php echo of_get_option('featured-title' . $fboxn, 'Simplicity Theme for Small  Business'); ?></h3>
<div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br />
<p><?php echo of_get_option('featured-description' . $fboxn , 'The Color changing  options of Simplicity will give the WordPress Driven Site an attractive look. Simplicity  is super elegant and Professional Responsive Theme which will create the business widely  expressed.'); ?></p>
</span>
```

Here is the code in the **style.css** file that renders the images:

```
#featured-boxs{padding:0 0 10px;display:block; margin: 0 -30px; text-align:center;}
.featured-box{width:210px;margin:0 15px 10px; display:inline-block; text-align:left;  vertical-align:top;}

.featured-box h3{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font-  size:15px;color:#555555;}
#featured-boxs h2{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font- size:19px;color:#555555;}
.featured-box-first{padding:20px 0;width:210px;margin:0;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image{border:3px solid #EEEEEE;width:202px;height:100px;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image:hover{box-shadow:0 0 11px 0px #555555;}
#featured-boxs img.box-icon{width:50px;height:50px;}
h3.featured-box2{width:140px;float:right;}
```

Comment: You need to join Stack Exchange's English Language network.

Answer (score 0):

Those featured 'posts' are extracted from your theme options. You'll need to add a new "featured-link" option among the "featured-title" and "featured-image".

I've not tested the following steps, but you'll get the idea.

### 1. Adding a Hyperlink Option for Simplicity Lite

Add this hyperlink option into line **89/90** of **simplicity-lite/inc/options.php**

```
$options[] = array(
  'name' => 'Hyperlink', 
  'desc' => 'Input the link for the Featured Areas.', 
  'id' => 'featured-hyperlink' . $fbsinumber,
  'std' => '#',
  'type' => 'text', );
```

Save the file and you'll see a new option in your theme options.

### 2. Output the Link

You can pull the info from your settings using this function which comes with the theme options:
`of_get_option()`. This functions accepts two parameters: `name` and `default value`. You can find out more about it in **simplicity-lite/inc/options-framework.php**, line **383**.

Lets wrap each of the images with an `a` tag and `href` it to the stored string in your settings.

**simplicity-lite/featured-box.php**, line **12**

```
<img class="box-image" src="<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn, get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn . '.png') ?>"/>
```

becomes

```
<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn) ? '<a href="' . of_get_option('featured-hyperlink' . $fboxn) . '">' : ''; ?>
  <img class="box-image" src="<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn, get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn . '.png') ?>"/>
<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn) ? '</a>' : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hassim for the help offered so far. I've made a some progress using the advice you offered me here. However, the challenge now is that when I click on the image it opens up the image itself and not the hyperlink supplied in the theme options. I request for you advice on how to overcome this challenge. Otherwise, thanks a lot everybody for reaching out esp. Hassim

Comment: I've edited a typo in the above example: <a href="' . of_get_option('featured-hyperlink' . $fboxn) . '"> instead of 'featured-image'