# Adding a Hyperlink to each of WordPress' Simplicity-Lite featured-box element

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a site for one of my very first clients using [Wordpress' Simplicity-Lite Theme.](http://wordpress.org/themes/simplicity-lite)
I'd like to alter the theme somehow so as to hyperlink my images in the featured-boxes position (Right below the slideshowshow) to open up a page in the same window. 
The problem is that the images are automatically generated/fetched by a PHP script that picks them up from the media gallery and so one script does it all for all the eight images. 
I want to make each of these images as fetched by PHP link to its own page to add interactivity to my site but I've tried several things including advice that I've received here before but all in vain both in the style.css and the featured-box.php files.
Below is a section of the PHP script in the featured-box.php file that fetches the 8 images and places them in the featured-boxes positions:

```
<div id="featured-boxs">
<?php foreach (range(1,8) as $fboxn) { ?>
<span class="featured-box"> 
<img class="box-image" src="<?php echo of_get_option('featured-image' . $fboxn,    get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/featured-image' . $fboxn . '.png') ?>"/>
<h3><?php echo of_get_option('featured-title' . $fboxn, 'Simplicity Theme for Small   Business'); ?></h3>
<div class="content-ver-sep"></div><br />
<p><?php echo of_get_option('featured-description' . $fboxn , 'The Color changing   options of Simplicity will give the WordPress Driven Site an attractive look. Simplicity   is super elegant and Professional Responsive Theme which will create the business widely   expressed.'); ?></p>
</span>
```

Here is the code in the style.css file that renders the images:

```
#featured-boxs{padding:0 0 10px;display:block; margin: 0 -30px; text-align:center;}
.featured-box{width:210px;margin:0 15px 10px; display:inline-block; text-align:left;   vertical-align:top;}

.featured-box h3{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font-   size:15px;color:#555555;}
#featured-boxs h2{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:100;font-  size:19px;color:#555555;}
.featured-box-first{padding:20px 0;width:210px;margin:0;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image{border:3px solid #EEEEEE;width:202px;height:100px;}
#featured-boxs img.box-image:hover{box-shadow:0 0 11px 0px #555555;}
#featured-boxs img.box-icon{width:50px;height:50px;}
h3.featured-box2{width:140px;float:right;}
```

Comment: Quick Googling of "of_get_option" lead me to a WordPress support thread which lead me to this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/. Is your theme using this plugin? You're going to have to edit `<img class="box-image" src...` PHP, and wrap it in an <a></a>. The problem is that this appears to be a poorly designed theme. It's using a custom loop using custom data, instead of WP_Query. You're going to have to figure out how to get the Post ID from inside the loop.

Comment: Yes. This theme is using the options-framework. I've tried wrapping as you've suggested but I'm stack on figuring out how to pick the Ids of the images fetched so that I can link each of them individually to a page/resource of my. Otherwise, when I wrap the code all images link to the same page; something I don't want.

Comment: Yep, finding the ID is going to be the hard part. You'll have to pick apart the custom loop they built. I try to stick to using WP_Query, and custom taxonomies, or custom post types. It's easier to understand, because it's standardized. I'd suggest looking for instances of $fboxn in other PHP files. Find how they are building it.

Comment: Just realized that you've asked this question 4 times...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Hyperlink to Wordpress' Simplicity-Lite featured-box element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053555/adding-a-hyperlink-to-wordpress-simplicity-lite-featured-box-element)